# Display and Pairing BLE devices on Bluetooth device list in [Settings]

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, settings

I'm developing a BLE peripheral device and would like to pair the device and iPhone on the Bluetooth devicelist ([Settings] -> [Bluetooth]).

I tested some Bluetooth(Classic) and BLE devices on the list and some devices were shown on the list but others weren't.

[Tested iPhone]

- iPhone5s (OSver. 7.0.4)
- iPhone6  (OSver. 8.0.2)

[Tested Bluetooth devices and result]

- Xperia Tablet Z2 (Classic) -> Shown
- Microsoft Wedge Mobile Keyboard (Classic) -> Shown
- Tag LBT-VRU01(BLE) -> Not shown
- Mouse BSMBB09DS (BLE) -> Not shown

Now I have two questions.

1. Is there any way to show and pair BLE devices on device list in [Settings] ?
2. Are there any conditions(specific profiles?) to show Bluetooth(Classic) peripheral devices on device list in [Settings].

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

iOS doesn't pair with BLE devices unless one of the device's characteristics specifies that encryption is required. Apps need to provide their own UI for the user to discover and select the BLE peripheral they want to work with (this is because the app knows what service(s) are required for the app while Bluetooth settings doesn't.

Even when pairing of BLE devices is performed it is still initiated through the app. Bluetooth settings is used to "forget" the device (remove the stored encryption keys).

Classic devices that offer a supported profile will appear in the Bluetooth settings screen. These are keyboards, hands free/headset and audio devices. Other MFi devices may also appear if there is an installed app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  
  
I'd like to know a little bit detail.  
  
Is my understanding next correct ?  

Even if the peripheral device is BLE(not Classic), the device which meet the following two conditions will be shown on the Bluetooth setting screen.  
1. Its characteristic requires encryption (such as CBCharacteristicPropertyNotifyEncryptionRequired, CBAttributePermissionsReadEncryptionRequired )  
2. iOS supports its profile (such as HID over GATT)  
  
Thanks and regards.

Comment: In case 1, the peripheral will appear once you attempt to read/write the encrypted characteristic and the user completes the pairing process.  In case 2 the device will appear if it is discoverable or paired

Comment: Sorry, my description in the question is not enough.
I'd like to know the way, if it exists,  to show my custom BLE devices "before paring".
I confirmed the application which I made can show the devices before paring.
I want to provide same function on the Bluetooth device list screen in [Settings] as well.
Thank you.

Comment: If it is a BLE GATT device, you can't.  If it is a HID or audio device, it will appear based on your device's discovery advertisements

Comment: I see. I will provide the paring function on my custom application. Thank you.

Comment: I would like to add that the BLE pairing can be initiated automatically without a UI in your app under certain circumstaces: If you access a BLE characteristic and your peripheral returns a "not authenticated error" if it is not paired, iOS will automatically initiate the BLE pairing.